# Adding custom validation rules to unobtrusive.min.js

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-validation

I've been trying to add custom

here is my input field with the attribute data-val-matchemail

```
<input type="text" name="5621755b-8bab-4a19-8c68-bf35860062fe" id="5621755b-8bab-4a19-8c68-bf35860062fe" class="text" value="" data-val-matchemail="email" maxlength="500">
```

and my custom rules in contour.js. My issue is that it is not firing

```
$.validator.addMethod('contour_matchemail', function (value, element) {
    console.log("contour_matchemail");
    return valid;
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("matchemail", "contour_matchemail");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool(....
```

Perhaps try something like this:

```
$('#your_form_id').validate();
$('#5621755b-8bab-4a19-8c68-bf35860062fe').rules('add', 'contour_matchemail');
```